# Issues with compound assignment and counting variables

Tags: python, pygame

**What I want to do:**

 For every ten seconds, the angle of the sprite changes. If the angle changes, add one to the degreeChange variable. When the aforementioned variable reaches five, change the day variable to one and reset the changeDegree variable. If the day reaches a month, or 30 days, the program ends.

While the program is running, it will display the day and it's respective temperature in the console.

**My issue:**

 There are two scenarios that happen: 1) there is no output, or 2) the program only prints the first 8 days and temperatures on a loop.

***Here is my code for reference:***

```py
    # create timer event
    change_delay = 10000 # 10 second(s)
    change_event = pg.USEREVENT + 1
    pg.time.set_timer(change_event, change_delay)

    angles = [0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315]
    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

            degreeChange = 0
            day = 0
            temp = [9, 14, 18, 18, 16, 21,
                    27, 23, 19, 25, 28, 28,
                    28, 25, 27, 27, 39, 50,
                    52, 46, 45, 46, 50, 50,
                    46, 46, 41, 43, 55, 61]

            # receive timer event
            if event.type == change_event:
                degreeChange += 1
                if degreeChange == 5:
                    degreeChange = degreeChange - 5
                    day += 1
                    print("day: ", day)
                    print("temp: ", temp[day])
                    if day >= 31:
                        pg.quit()
                for i in range(0, 7):
                # change angle by 45°
                    ball.vel = ball.vel.rotate(angles[i])
```

*Let me know if you need to see the rest of my code.
Thanks :)*

Comment: Why are you rotating the `ball.vel` with *every* value in `angles`, *each* change_event? And if that "vel" stands for "velocity"... if you want to change the facing of the sprite, why are you changing its velocity?

Comment: I am changing the velocity because my program is a grid with a ball moving around it. I am changing the velocity in order to change the direction the ball is going on the screen (Think: The DVD logo on a blank screen, instead it changes its path every ten seconds by a set angle.) Can you elaborate a bit more on your first question? What do you mean by, "...with every value in angles, each change_event"?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

        degreeChange = 0
        day = 0
```

Every time you grab an event from the event queue, therefore, the `degreeChange` and `day` values reset. This is clearly not what you want, since it resets before every possible opportunity to increment the `degreeChange` - thus it can only ever be 0 or 1.

Comment: How would I stop it from doing that?

Comment: @DougJames Move the initialization (`degreeChange = 0`, `day = 0`) before the application loop (before  `while`)